# Bootstrap 3 checkbox doesn't align with form label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="property_feature" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 control-label">ফিচার</label>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4">
           <label class="checkbox-inline">
               <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="property_furnished" name="feature">আসবাবপত্রে সজ্জিত
           </label>
           <label class="checkbox-inline">
               <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="property_sublet" name="feature">সাবলেট
           </label>
           <label class="checkbox-inline">
               <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="property_mess" name="feature">মেস
           </label>
        </div>
</div>
```

The above code gives me following output. But I want everything to be displayed as inline. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A more bootstrap focused approach would to be to restructure your code like such:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="property_feature">ফিচার</label>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="property_furnished">আসবাবপত্রে সজ্জিত</label>
      <input value="1" id="property_furnished" name="feature" type="checkbox">        
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="property_sublet">সাবলেট</label>
      <input value="2" id="property_sublet" name="feature" type="checkbox">    
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="property_mess">মেস   </label>
      <input value="3" id="property_mess" name="feature" type="checkbox">        
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

One of the main issues in your code is that your first label is OUTSIDE of your div class that sets the column position. So you aren't including it in the col-md-offset-4 that you specify.

Here's a bootply http://www.bootply.com/ekh1Cpmeht
You will most likely want to adjust the spacing between the `property_feature` label and the `property_furnished` .

Comment: but i use form-horizontal class

Comment: Your question states you want everything to be in-line. So do you want it in-line or like a the form-horizontal example on bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `display: inline-block;` because Div will break down to new line the checkbox.

```
.col-md-8.col-sm-8.col-md-offset-4 {
    display: inline-block;
}

.col-md-4.col-sm-4.control-label {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yw2a3yr8/)

Comment: yes, but if this change cause effect all of the design ?? @ketan

Comment: @AlHizbulBahar Not at all. you can also use `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block` in some cases.

Comment: @AlHizbulBahar What not working will you be specific or create fiddle which is not working?